# Get certain data from different tables for each date

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

I have two tables

- X with columns id,date and count
- another table is Y with columns id,code.

Now i want the results in the mentioned form so that there should be columns code, id, and count at different dates in different columns so it should look like this

```
TABLE X
        id date         count
        1  2016-08-16     20
        1  2016-08-17     34
        1  2016-08-18     56
        1  2016-08-19     67
        1  2016-08-20     87

TABLE Y
id  code
1    101
2    102
3    103
4    104
5    105

RESULT
        CODE    ID   2016-08-16 2016-08-17 2016-08-18  2016-08-19  2016-08-20                                    
        101       1  20         34         56          67          87
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is this enough?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is just a sample data, the actual data is very large

Comment: how many unique dates do you actually have?

you could use case to pivot the data but if there are alot of dates i would suggest you wont be able to write a query but will need to write a procedure to do it

Comment: @Tik around 60 dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A simple method to get similar result is

   ```
   SELECT y.code, y.id, json_object_agg(x.date, x.count)
   FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.id GROUP BY y.id, y.code
   ```

   If you use another language to process the query result, I think this one is good enough.
2. If the date columns need to be dynamic, I think PL/pgSQL is necessary.

   ```
   DO $$
   BEGIN
       EXECUTE (SELECT format('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result AS
           SELECT code, id, %s FROM (
               SELECT y.code, y.id, json_object_agg(x.date, x.count) AS counts
               FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.id GROUP BY y.id, y.code) as sub',
               string_agg(DISTINCT 'counts->>''' || date :: TEXT || ''' AS ' || '"' || date :: TEXT || '"', ',')
           ) FROM x);
   END
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   SELECT * FROM result;
   ```

Comment: Can you explain how to use the first method?

Comment: It depends on which language do you use. The third column will be an object or hash table in that language, and you can read value from it.